# How can I hide block of text using YouTrack Markdown syntax?

Tags: youtrack

When I use YouTrack Wiki syntax, I can use `{cut}` like this:

```
{cut Block title}
Block content
{cut}
```

This is very useful feature, but Wiki syntax is deprecated and I can't find something similar in YouTrack Markdown syntax.

**UPD**: I figured out that I can use `stacktrace` as language with backticks:

````
```stacktrace
Header text
Hidden text
```
````

But it works different (possibly because it was designed to work with Java stacktraces), not preserving leading whitespaces, not highlighting code, etc.

Comment: Makrdown syntax in YouTrack has nothing similar to that. If in need of an invisible note consider leaving a private comment.

Comment: Private comment is not suitable because hidden text should be visible for all users. I need to hide big portion of minor information to make issue description/comment more compact

Comment: Then you'd better vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-45636

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In YouTrack 2019.3 it will be possible to use this (not tested personally yet):

```
<details>
  <summary>Brief summary</summary>
  Unnecessary long description
</details>
```

Implemented in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-45636

Comment: YouTrack 2019.3 also brings HTML comment support, which is somewhat closer to what's requested: `<!-- -->`

Answer (score 1):

On the subject of invisible notes, I use the following which do not show at all when using Markdown:

```
[//]: # (COMMENT DOES NOT SHOW)
```

This is great if doing a default description which needs some type of instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Combining `<details>` with a code block almost seemed like it wouldn't work, but it does work with a blank line after the `<summary>`:

````html
<details><summary>This is the title.</summary>

```stacktrace
long stack trace
```
</details>
````

For some reason, without the blank line it doesn't interpret the ``` as markup.

YouTrack also seems to save it with a blank line after the closing ``` and before the close tag `</details>` but this doesn't seem to be strictly necessary when editing it manually.